# Generator and Discriminator Loss in Image Colorization

Tags: python, tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network

I have been following the image colorization from GAN. I have tried to implement the research paper myself but I got a problem. The generator and discriminator loss is not converging after a certain point. So, I guess there is a problem in their implementation. Here is the code

```
def generator_loss(self,fake_output_discri,generated_image_from_generator, actual_image,regularizer_lambda=0.01):
        mse = tf.reduce_mean(regularizer_lambda*tf.keras.losses.mean_absolute_error(generated_image_from_generator, actual_image))
        return tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = tf.ones_like(fake_output_discri),logits = fake_output_discri) + mse

def discriminator_loss(self,generated_image_from_generator,actual_image):
        actual_loss  = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = tf.ones_like(actual_image), logits = actual_image )
        fake_loss  = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = tf.zeros_like(generated_image_from_generator), logits = generated_image_from_generator)
        return actual_loss + fake_loss
```

Assuming that the parameter passed to them are correct, am I doing anything wrong? I tried printing the generator and discriminator loss, and it remains constant after certain epochs! Here is the train function that does most of the job!

```
def train(self,gray_scale_image_dataset,color_image_dataset,test_image):

    generator = self.generator_model()
    discriminator = self.discriminator_model()

    gen_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate)
    dis_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate)
    for eachEpoch in range(self.epochs):

        with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
            for i in range(20):
                random.shuffle(gray_scale_image_dataset)
                random.shuffle(color_image_dataset)
            gray_scale_dataset_image = gray_scale_image_dataset[:self.batch_size]
            color_dataset_image_batch = color_image_dataset[:self.batch_size]

            generated_image = generator(gray_scale_dataset_image)
            real_output = discriminator(color_dataset_image_batch)
            fake_output = discriminator(generated_image)

            gen_loss = self.generator_loss(fake_output,generated_image,color_dataset_image_batch)
            dis_loss = self.discriminator_loss(fake_output,real_output)
            print("generator = {} discriminator =  {}".format(gen_loss,dis_loss))            
        gen_gradients = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss,generator.trainable_variables)
        disc_gradients = disc_tape.gradient(dis_loss,discriminator.trainable_variables)
        print("APPLYING GRADENTS")
        gen_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gen_gradients, generator.trainable_variables))
        dis_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(disc_gradients, discriminator.trainable_variables))

        print ("EPOCHS COMPLETED = {} ".format(eachEpoch))
        #for drawing test_image
        self.draw_images(generator,test_image)
```